# ListView.SelectedItems[0] Selection Error

Tags: c#, listview, foreach

Why is my program returning the following error?

Please be specific thanks.

PS: For whatever reason when there is only one item in the `listview` it works.

> **Error:** InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.  Parameter name: index

Code:

```
if(e.Control == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string s = "";
                    string sCheck = "";
                    int select = 0;
                    int i = 0;
                    int position = 0;

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        i--;
                    }

                    if(select >= 1)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            select--;
                        } while (select >= 1);
                    }

                    if (position >= 1)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            position--;
                        } while (position >= 1);
                    }

                    foreach (object item1 in listView1.Items)
                    {
                        if (item1 == listView1.SelectedItems[select])
                        {
                            s = listView1.SelectedItems[select].Text;
                            sCheck = item1.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(item1.ToString());

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            select++;
                        }
                    }
                    string s1 = "";


                    foreach (object item in listView1.Items)
                    {
                        if (sCheck == item.ToString())
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
                            i++;
                            position++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            position++;
                        }
                    }

                    string s2 = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
                    s1 = position.ToString();

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        string result = "Item: " + s + " || Position: " + s1 + " || Total Items: " + s2;
                        MessageBox.Show(result, "ListView Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select a Item");
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no selected items the code will throw an exception at `if (item1 == listView1.SelectedItems[select])` as there is no element at `[0]` in the collection.

Also, I believe the following code would have the same result as yours:

```
try
{
    foreach (var item in listView1.SelectedItems) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    }

    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        var result = string.Format("Item: {0} || Position: {1} || Total Items: {2}", 
            listView1.SelectedItems[0], listView1.SelectedItems.Count, listView1.Items.Count);

        MessageBox.Show(result, "ListView Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select a Item");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The first three `if` statments are redundant as they occur directly after the variables are assigned (i.e, how could `i` equal 1 if you've just initialized it to 0?)

The two `foreach` loops show the same thing (show a message box with the selected items).

Position gets incremented for every selected item so it's always going to equal the total selected items.

If you provide more detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve I will try to help.